# How to run curl commands parallel using GNU parallel

Tags: bash, curl, gnu-parallel

Just recently started programming in bash. I want to run curl command for 'n' times where n is user input. And I want to run in parallel. I came across GNU Parallel.
the curl code for running n times is

```
ip1="some ip"
ip2="some ip"
ip3="some ip"
for ((j=1; j<= $servers;))
do
    for ((i= 1; i<= $val; i++))
    do
        c=ip$j
        value=scatest"$j$i"
        curl -s -X POST ${!c}:4000/invoke -H "content-type: application/json" -d '{"args":["org1","'$value'","27-06-2018"]}'
        if ((i % $val == 0))
        then
            ((j++))
        fi
    done
done
```

i want to run this curl command equally and parallel on these different hosts based on the user input. Can any one help me out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fairly simple to parallelize per server:

```
val=1000
doit() {
    server="$1"
    serverno="$2"
    for ((i= 1; i<= $val; i++))
    do
        value=scatest"$serverno$i"
        curl -s -X POST ${server}:4000/invoke -H "content-type: application/json" -d '{"args":["org1","'$value'","27-06-2018"]}'
    done
}
export -f doit
export val
parallel -j0 doit {} {#} ::: serverip1 serverip2 ...
```

If you can accept `scatest` has a different value you can parallelize even further:

```
doit() {
    server="$1"
    jobno="$2"
    i="$3"
    value=scatest"$jobno$i"
    curl -s -X POST ${server}:4000/invoke -H "content-type: application/json" -d '{"args":["org1","'$value'","27-06-2018"]}'
}
export -f doit
seq $val | parallel -j0 doit {1} {#} {2} ::: serverip1 serverip2 ... :::: -
```